# Switching between views in android data retained if any

Tags: android

I am new to android development (and also a java newbie) and I noticed that when I switch between views I noticed that any variables declared as static in the view class retains its value but the rest are gone. So I have the following questions if some one is kind enough to answer --

1. When to use static for variables if any?
2. If I want to retain the state of say my game between these switches (say to see the score or something), what is the way to do it? Is it by using static variables in the class to store everything? If so how do I reset the variables for a new game?

Answer (score 0):

- When to use static for variables if any?

Static variables should be use when multiple activities needs access on it. In other words, if you think your variable has global usage, then setting it as `public static` may help.

- If I want to retain the state of say my game between these switches (say to see the score or something), what is the way to do it? Is it by using static variables in the class to store everything? If so how do I reset the variables for a new game?

You need to override onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save and restore the values of your variables. A tutorial on how to use it can be found here: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/09/onsaveinstancestate-and.html .